# I want to download the file remotely to server instead of computer

Tags: php

I am using PDFcrowd API and implemented in my code.

It generates a PDF for me, but it downloads the file to the computer and I want it to store it locally.

My code so far:

```
// convert a web page and store the generated PDF into a $pdf variable
$pdf = $client->convertURI($url);

// set HTTP response headers
header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
header("Cache-Control: max-age=0");
header("Accept-Ranges: none");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$pdfName."\"");

echo $pdf;
```

Comment: Take a look at the [fwrite](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) functions, and also [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) function.

Comment: Then don't echo it back to the client?

Comment: file_put_contents solved my problem thanks a lot